# Is there a convention in quantum circuit diagrams for specific quantum measurements?

Tags: quantum-circuit, terminology-and-notation

Is there a convention in quantum circuit diagrams for specific quantum measurements? For example, how could one express the measurement $|0\rangle \langle 0|$ in a circuit diagram?

Comment: people usually just use the little multimeter in circuit diagrams (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416058)) but it sounds like you're asking how to denote a specific projective measurement? for something like $|0\rangle\langle 0|$ you could just use wiring diagrams for tr$($(thing you're measuring)$|0\rangle\langle 0|)$

Comment: Thanks! Could you possibly provide an example of the latter? I am not entirely sure what this would look like.